# How to design a parallel code for a Fibonacci algorithm, but without openmp tasks?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, fibonacci

I want to write a c++ code for calculating Fibonacci numbers in parallel, with a use of OpenMP tools. I know that, with `#pragma omp task`, the code will be:

```
int fib(int n) {
int i, j;
if (n<2)
    return n;
else {
    #pragma omp task shared(i)
    i=fib(n-1);
    #pragma omp task shared(j)
    j=fib(n-2);
    #pragma omp taskwait
    return i+j;
    }
}
```

Computing this way is not cool, since each thread is waiting for its child threads to complete their work, so the whole process is still a sequential!

I want to write the parallel code, using this equation:

F(n + k) = F(n + 1) * F(k) + F(n) * F(k - 1)

Would anyone help me to do this?

Comment: I think a better question would have been "Is there a parallel Fibonacci sequence algorithm which is more efficient than a sequential one?" I think the answer to that is no. But I would like to be proven wrong. The OpenMP example for the Fibonacci sequence using tasks is useful only for education on how to use tasks but I don't think you would ever want to do this in practice. It's a bit like using Monte Carlo to calculate pi which is often used as an example. You would never want to do that in practice.

Comment: You could use the golden ratio to calculation the starting Fn for each thread and then have the threads proceed sequentially. For example if you wanted F0 through F99 and you have two threads then you could have thread1 started at F0 and thread2 start at F50 using the golden ratio to calculate F0 and F50. But eventually this becomes memory bandwidth bound anyway. The question becomes why would you want to write out a long sequence in the first place?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio

Comment: The analytic solution using the golden ratio is limited to small n. A better solution using matrix squaring. I may try that.

Answer (score 2):

This way is "cool" and works in parallel. Note that `taskwait` does allow the thread to execute some other task, e.g. a task created by it's own child task. Just to illustrate a possible execution schedule:

```
* creating a task , # actually waiting for all child tasks
           ------- time --->
Thread 1   {fib(4): **b      {fib(2): ** {fib(1): ret 1}   # ret 1+0}         # ret 2+1
Thread 2            {fib(3): ** {fib(1): ret 1}                     # ret 1+1}
Thread 3             {fib(2): ** {fib(0): ret 0} ret 1+0}
Thread 4                      {fib(1): ret 1}{fib(0): ret 0}
```

Of course this the code is still horribly inefficient compared to iterative computation. Also in actual code using tasking on recursive algorithms, the creation of new tasks should be stopped after a certain recursion depth to manage the task creation overhead.

Comment: If one takes a fair amount of efforts, benchmarking will show, that recursive expression of a workflow is easy for human need to formulate a problem-solution approach, but not making such formulation any better in a sense of a code-execution performance. Add a set of primitive, context un-aware syntax constructors, that change a code-execution flow on an increadible scale, and the `#pragma` decoratored code soon results in bad habits. With selective exception possible, recursive formulations of a problem solutions are **`[PARALLEL]` anti-pattern**. Just test & **post `fib( 1E+12 ) in [ns]`**

Comment: What are you trying to say? Obviously it's a educational example... which I did not chose. **I did even remark on the inefficiency of recursive fibonacci** in my answer. However, recursive algorithms and their parallelization with tasks are a relevant thing.

Comment: I try to say, that a serious professional ought never pass a fragile piece of code. Not even if taken from a school-book example. Never. What might work ( having an incredibly poor performance ) on small numbers, will crash the process. A professional designer never lets a risk of crashing a process. This is a lack of one's professional responsibility. Just **test & post `fib( 1E+12 ) in [ns]` if still in doubts** about the meaning. Parallel-processing requires a lot more resources-management efforts and professional responsibility for detecting fragility and avoiding un-avoidable crashes.

Comment: I'm well aware of the limitations and have clearly addressed them in my answer. Why don't you provide an answer to the question that maintains your idea of *professional responsibility* and explains how you go about *avoiding un-avoidable crashes*. Also believe it or not - in a few real cases you can just slap on a `#pragma omp task` on a tree-walking recursive algorithm and get a serious professional parallel-processing solution - as for the majority of more complicated cases, you gotta start somewhere understanding and learning...

Comment: If recursive task-based algorithms are never the way to go, then you could explain why they outperform in some cases their parallel iterative form. In other cases, you cannot simply transform the algorithm. FFTs for example are recursive by nature. In addition, as @Zulan explained in the answer, recursion depth cut-off easily addresses the efficiency problem (sometimes even the compilers are able to transform the remaining serial-part recursive code into an iterative one, transparently to the programmer).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative parallel solution which directly calculates `fib(n)` and `fib(n+1)` using the golden ratio and then calculates the rest of the sequence sequentially for each thread. I got the direct solution from [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#D).

The problem is that the direct calculations overflows for `n>72` so this method is almost certainly slower than calculating the first 71 numbers sequentially and in any case 64-bit integers overflows for `n>92`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <omp.h>

uint64_t fib(unsigned m) { // Direct Calculation, correct for abs(m) <= 71
  double sqrt5r =  1.0 / sqrt(5.0);      
  double golden = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0))/2.0;
  return rint(pow(golden, m)*sqrt5r);
}

void fib_sequence(unsigned n, uint64_t *f) {
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    size_t t  = omp_get_thread_num();
    size_t nt = omp_get_num_threads();
    int x0 = (t+0)*n/nt;
    int x1 = (t+1)*n/nt;
    f[x0 + 0] = fib(x0 + 0);
    f[x0 + 1] = fib(x0 + 1);
    for(int i=x0+2; i<x1; i++) {
      f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int n = 71;
  uint64_t f1[n], f2[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) f1[i] = fib(i);
  fib_sequence(n, f2);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) if(f1[i] != f2[i]) printf("%d\n", i);
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("F%d: %" PRId64 " %" PRId64 "\n", i, f1[i], f2[i]);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends did a cool trick when he did parallelization of finding n Fibonacci numbers. 
We all know that kth fibonacci number can be found in log(k) time using [matrix exponentation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/). 
Also fibonacci(j) only depends on fibonacci(j - 1) and fibonacci(j - 2) 
Suppose you have four threads, then first thread will be given task of finding 0 to (n/4)-1 fibonacci numbers iteratively.
Now second thread has to find fibonacci numbers from n/4 to 2n/4 - 1 but for that it needs fibo(n/4 - 1). Well now the trick is this thread will calculate fibo(n/4) and fibo(n/4 + 1) using matrix exponentation in O(log(n)) time (Not much time right and clever too because we are not waiting for first thread's end result). Now as soon as the second thread gets fibo(n/4) and fibo(n/4 + 1), it will in parallel with other threads find fibonacci numbers from n/4 to 2n/4 - 1. 
Similarly the third thread will first using matrix exponentation find fibo(2n/4) and fibo(2n/4 + 1) and it will in parallel with other threads find fibonacci numbers from 2n/4 to 3n/4 - 1. 
And the last fourth thread will do similarly. 
Now if you ask for performance, each thread among available p theads will spend at most 2log(n) time and do n/p iterations that will take O(n/p) time. So each thread will do at most the work of O(n/p + log(n)) and the speedup would be pn / n + plog(n) 
Hope that helps!